# Why is it not printing a string when i call a class method

Tags: python, oop, class-method

Im just playing around with python OOP, and when I call this class method I get `<__main__.User object at 0x7fb889516220>`

**code**

```py
 class User:
  users = []

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.users.append(self)

  @classmethod
  def num_user(cls):
    return len(cls.users)

  @classmethod
  def viewUsers(cls):
    print(f"Number of users: {len(cls.users)}")
    for user in cls.users:
      print("\t- ", user)

  @staticmethod
  def isAllowed(age):
    return age >= 10

name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))

if User.isAllowed(age) == False:
  print(f"Sorry, {name.title()}. \nYou must be 10 or above to enter!\n")
    

else:
  print(f"Welcome, {name.title()}!\n")
    
  User(name).viewUsers()
```

I want it to print the names of the users. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by slightly changing your `viewUsers` function.
Currently, it is printing the `User` object instead make it print the `name`

```
  @classmethod
  def viewUsers(cls):
    print(f"Number of users: {len(cls.users)}")
    for user in cls.users:
      print("\t- ", user.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very minor bug. You were appending `User` objects to `users` but in the `viewUsers` method you wanted to `print` their names. Simply replace printing the `user` with `user.name`. The updated code is below.

```
class User:
    users = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.users.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def num_user(cls):
        return len(cls.users)

    @classmethod
    def viewUsers(cls):
        print(f"Number of users: {len(cls.users)}")
        for user in cls.users:
            print("\t- ", user.name)

    @staticmethod
    def isAllowed(age):
        return age >= 10

name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))

if User.isAllowed(age) == False:
    print(f"Sorry, {name.title()}. \nYou must be 10 or above to enter!\n")
else:
    print(f"Welcome, {name.title()}!\n")

User(name).viewUsers()
```